# ThisIsNotAObjectReference error when accessing component of returning parameter

Tags: reference, components, abap

I'm getting **ThisIsNotAObjectReference** syntax message when trying to handle a fully typed data reference expression like this:

```
method getDataReference.
 rr_value = ref #( varStructure ).
endmethod.

data(lr_value) = object->getDataReference( )->structureComponent.
```

I understand the syntax is identical for retrieving object references but how to deal with fully typed data references in expressions?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot chain method calls with reference component accesses. You should use auxiliary variable like here:

```
CLASS lcl_class DEFINITION.
PUBLIC SECTION.
 METHODS: getdatareference RETURNING VALUE(rr_value) TYPE REF TO mara.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_class IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD getdatareference.
    DATA: ls_mara TYPE mara.
    rr_value = REF #( ls_mara ).
    SELECT SINGLE * FROM mara INTO rr_value->*.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  DATA(lcl)     = NEW lcl_class( ).
  DATA(lv_mara) = lcl->getdatareference( ).
  DATA(l_matnr) = lv_mara->matnr.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of speculating about what you're trying to achieve here but as far as I know you'll need to dereference data reference before you can access their contents. The following extends the code you posted above.

```
report ztest.

class lcl_test definition.

  public section.

    methods getDataReference
      returning value(rr_value) type ref to tadir.

  private section.

    data varStructure type tadir.

endclass.

class lcl_test implementation.

  method getDataReference.

    varstructure-author = sy-uname.
    rr_value = ref #( varStructure ).

  endmethod.

endclass.

start-of-selection.

  data(object) = new lcl_test( ).
  data(lr_value) = object->getDataReference( ).

  field-symbols <structure> type tadir.
  assign lr_value->* to <structure>. " This is the dereferencing step
  write / <structure>-author.
```